# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController display all contact data in a single cel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, abpeoplepickerview

Hi  i am developing a app where when i click contacts it goes to ABpeoplePicekrNavigationcontroller and display all contacts in the form of list in the table.But i want to select all contacts so that i want to perform some action.So how can i achive this.

I am not sure this is the right question to ask.Actually i am trying to send the contact information to next screen instead of selecting single contact information  everytime i want to select whole contact list.So how can i do this??

I thought i show them to show in single cell even though space doesnt fit in single cell.just show them single cell so that selecting one cell which contains all contact information would be better to send..

So can anyone suggest me right way to select all the contacts list rather than selecting one contact..I donno whether we can do this or not??if so how???if not what is the other way??
Here is the below code where i am using for accessing the contact list.

```
- (IBAction)configureMyContact:(id)sender {
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
peoplePicker.navigationBar.topItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"CHOOSE_CONTACT_TITLE", @"Defining my contact title.");
[self presentModalViewController:peoplePicker animated:YES];
[peoplePicker release];
}


- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
  shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

myContactID = ABRecordGetRecordID(person);
[self refreshMyContactButton];
[self saveMyContactID:myContactID];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

return NO;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
  shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                            property:(ABPropertyID)property
                          identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{
return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your record using this

```
- (void)getPersonOutOfAddressBook
{    
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

    if (addressBook != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Succesful.");

        NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

        NSUInteger i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < [allContacts count]; i++)
        {            
            ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];



            NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

            NSString *lastName =  (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

            ABMultiValueRef mobile=ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

            for (int k=0;k<ABMultiValueGetCount(mobile); k++)
            {
                NSString *mobileNo = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(mobile, k);
            }


            //email
            ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonEmailProperty);

            NSUInteger j = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); j++)
            {
                NSString *email = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, j);
            }

        }
    }
    CFRelease(addressBook);
}
```

Comment: USing this i can fetch all the contacts in the address book at a time??where do i need to use this function?

Comment: where you want to use all contact?

Comment: i mean to say when it moves to address book instead of selecting one contact i want to entire contacts in the address book is it possible to select entire Address book.

Comment: yes using this code you will get entire address book, call this code in code in viewDidLoad, and add data in array

Comment: your welcome.. :) you sent me msg over facebook , but i am unable to reply, because i am blocked for 30 days .. :( send friend req i will accept:)